# select column name from a specific table by position sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
 TABLE
COLUMN1
COLUMN2
COLUMN3
```

I need to know how to get the column name by the position:

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE POSITION = 2;
```

> result: "COLUMN2"

Comment: So what happens when a new column is added before position 2?

Comment: I am really curios to know what problem you are trying to solve. Are you trying to iterate through each column to get its name? It is possible to get column positions and names.  In a database system the column position is completely irrelevant.  Most of SQL doesn't know the position of columns, but only knows the column names.  If you are writing a select clause with columns positions you are going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the permission to read data from the `information_schema` database, you can do this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE'
    AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 2;
```

As stated [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091249/select-column-name-from-a-specific-table-by-position-sql#comment24722413_17091249), it is not good database management and you are going wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could read `COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION`, but this sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

You can (and always should!) quote column names in , e.g. `SELECT colname`. This will handle cases of table names being Condition or `SELECT`.

**EDIT - This is a really really evil thing to do, I wouldn't.**